# Writting and reading from a binary file doesn't work

Tags: c, binaryfiles

So, i'm tring to write 9 numbers into a binary file and then read them from that file and print them to the screen, but for some reason it is not working and i can't figure out why.I've tried to look for the answer on the internet, but nothing seem to help. If someone could point out the maistake in my code (which is probably very obvious, but i'm a newbie in c), i would be extremly thankful.
Here is the code:

```
int main()
 {
    FILE *f;
    if(f=fopen("dat", "wb") == NULL){
      return 1;
    }
   int c;
   for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
     c = fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, f);
     printf("%d",c); //it prints 0 every single time, as if nothing was written in the file
  }
  fclose(f);
  if(f=fopen("dat", "rb+")==NULL){
    return 1;
  }
  int a;
  while(fread(&a, sizeof(int), 1, f)){
    printf("%d\n", a);
  }
  fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Empty file. No errors.

Comment: Use a debugger to find the **probable** site of the error... then google with code from *that* area.

Comment: Also enable all compiler warnings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an issue about *operator precedence*.

Pay attention to the comparison and the assignment performed inside the `if` statement:

```
if (f = fopen("dat", "wb") == NULL)
```

The comparison operator (`==`) has a higher precedence than the assignment operator (`=`). The code above is actually equivalent to:

```
if (f = (fopen("dat", "wb") == NULL))
```

That is, the result of the call to `fopen()` is first being compared against `NULL` and then the result of this comparison is assigned to `f`.

What you actually want is:

```
if ((f = fopen("dat", "wb")) == NULL)
```

That is, first assign the result of `fopen()` to `f` and then perform the comparison against `NULL`.

The same applies to your second call to `fopen()`.

Comment: @sale but you miss/lay us, that `prtintf` does his output